# Excel format cells

Tags: excel, format

I have custom format cells but I don't know what does it meaning? Could you guys help me? Thank you.

```
0.0_);[Red](0.0)
```

P/s Is there any reference documents about this format ? If it exist please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number format in excel can have up to 4 sections,

```
<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>
```

This formatting will apply if the number in a cell is positive, negative, zero or a text respectively. In your case the format has 2 sections which is for positive and zeroes and then one for negatives.

```
0.0_); - for positive and zeroes
[Red](0.0) - for negatives
```

1) `0.0` - This is to format all the numbers to a single decimal place. For example 1234 will become 1234.0 and 1234.56 will become 1234.5

2) `_)` - the underscore followed by a parentheses ) is to apply spacing at the end so that it is inline with the negatives which are enclosed with parentheses.

3) `[Red]()` - negatives will be represented in red color font enclosed with parentheses.

A picture can speak a thousand words,

[image]

You can find more info and much more helpful formatting methods in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) and of course `google`